# Can I sign arbitrary PDFs through DocuSign without preparing signature fields?

Tags: pdf, docusignapi

Use case: My system needs to retrieve authorization forms from a variety of sources. There is no standard form - each source may define their own authorization form, but each authorization form requires exactly one signature. None of the blank forms will have PDF signature field markup - they will just be simple PDFs originally meant for printing and wet signing.  For example, every summer camp in the country has their own release form. My system will receive those forms and present them for signature, without knowing what the form looks like ahead of time.

This means I will not have the chance to mark up the form with DocuSign "Sign Here" boxes.

Is it possible in DocuSign to have a system send in a form and allow the signer to manually determine exactly where they want to place their signature? Without giving the signer duties such as preparing the document themselves - I just want them to see the form on screen, and be prompted to "Click wherever you think you should sign", just like they would do in the paper world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DocuSign [free form signing](https://support.docusign.com/guides/signer-guide-signing-free-form-new) for your usecase.

See this DocuSign [Blog Post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-guided-signing-versus-free-form-signing/) for more information.

> **Free-form signing** occurs when no tags are placed on a document submitted via DocuSign. This means that the signer will be presented with a palette of signature options (Signature, Initial, Full Name, etc.) which can be applied to the document at will.